# Getting snakemake environment variables local to a compute node in cluster execution

Tags: snakemake, pbs

Is there a way to lazy evaluate variables in the `shell` directive of snakemake?

Our PBS computing cluster creates a node-local scratch directory for every submitted job and sets the value of `$TMPDIR` to the path to this directory during the execution. After the job ends, this temporary scratch directory gets deleted. Since snakemake is creating the jobscripts (which are later `qsub`'ed to PBS) on the login node and at a point in time where the temporary scratch is not even created, I'm unable to use the scratch directory for efficient job grouping. This way I have to read and write the files back and forth on the NFS.

I tried using `shadow` and setting the `shadow-dir` to `$TMPDIR`, but again, the correct value is only set after the jobscript got parsed by PBS.

**Update**: workaround https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/522

Comment: Isn't the `tmpdir` `resource` exactly for that purpose as it is late evaluated? See here: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#standard-resources But maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question :/

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is "no".

But if you were to give this [feature request](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2315) some love by commenting or upvoting then we might be able to get the attention of the devs a little sooner.

Comment: Hi, see the link in the updated question. Snakemake contributors  provided a workaround for the problem.